# get share count for google and twitter with php not working anymore

Tags: php, twitter, google-plus

I use to get social share count with theses functions:

```
function get_tweets($url) {
    $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . rawurlencode($url));
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
}

function get_fb($url) {
    $json_string = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls='.rawurlencode($url));
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json[0]['total_count'])?intval($json[0]['total_count']):0;
}

function get_pinterest($url) {
    $return_data = $this->file_get_contents_curl('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url='.rawurlencode($url));
    $json_string = preg_replace('/^receiveCount((.*))$/', "\1", $return_data);
    $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
    return isset($json['count'])?intval($json['count']):0;
}

private function file_get_contents_curl($url){
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    $cont = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        die(curl_error($ch));
    }
    return $cont;
}

function get_plusones($url)  {
    $contents = file_get_contents('https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url='.rawurlencode( $url ));
    preg_match( '/window\.__SSR = {c: ([\d]+)/', $contents, $matches );
    return isset($matches[0]) ? (int)str_replace('window.__SSR = {c: ', '', $matches[0]) : 0;

}
```

Since 2 days, it is not working anymore for twitter and google and I got this error:

```
failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

I think my ip has been banned by google and twitter but I'm not sure of it.
Is there someone who can confirm my hypothesis?

If i go through javascript solution, will it work?

Answer (score -1):

The manual for php_curl: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE will tell you the HTTP response code sent by API servers. Try to log it or print it on the page, if you are in testing environment. If the response code is something like 403, the API server have rejected requests sent from your server.

Comment: Author attached error message and this is not a proper answer for the question. It should be a comment.